# Solace Subscription Manager for wildcard topics

Tags: solace

I tried the On-Behalf-Of subscription feature to add topics for mqtt clients and found out that it only works for the following topic structure:
T1/T2/T3
T1/T2/T3/*

but not for the following (wildcards):
T1/T2/T3/>
T1/T2/T3/+

I wonder how I can add multi-level topic subscription for my mqtt clients.

I am using sol-common 7.1.2.230 and sol-jcsmp 7.1.2.230 and my Solace appliance version is soltr_7.1.1.582.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The On-Behalf-Of subscription feature is only supported for SMF clients and therefore only subscription topics using SMF syntax are accepted.

When using an SMF client to manage subscriptions for a MQTT client, the ">" wildcard is not allowed because there is no MQTT equivalent. The ">" wildcard means the following path must match 1 or more topic levels, whereas in MQTT, the "#" means that the following path must match 0 or more topic levels.

The reason the "+" wildcard doesn't work is because it is not valid SMF syntax.

On the other hand, the "*" wildcard is the exact equivalent of the "+" wildcard in MQTT. This is why the "*" wildcard works.